# VBA Round Function

Tags: excel, vba, rounding

In one of my programs I need to calculate the average on a range of numbers.  The problem is that sometimes the answer comes out to a huge decimal and I need to try and get that down to two decimal places maximum.

I've seen something called `Excel.WorksheetFunction.Round(...)` but as far as I know it only works with a specific number or a specific cell.  I was wondering if anyone knew how to implement this so that it will round all decimals in a range of cells.

```
Excel.WorksheetFunction.Round(ActiveSheet.Range(g_first_Function_Col & "2:" & g_first_Function & g_totalRow).Select, 2)
```

The code above attempts to use the round function on a range of cells.  The g_first_Function_Col is some column (like column "H") and g_totalRow is the last row that has any values in it.  When I try to run this bit of code it tells me "=" expected.  Essentially I'm trying to select an entire column and round it.

Thank you,

Jesse Smothermon

Comment: Interesting approach, may I ask why you need to round each cell? It sounds to me from your question that summing the total and then rounding that would work?

Comment: Basically the program accepts up to four user inputs for what kind of operation that want (that can be applied to a range of cells) such as sum, average, median, max, etc.  I don't really know what the answers are until they are in the output because I just use the excel functions, I don't actually save anything anywhere until output.  Since I don't know the answers I want to do this on all the cells at once in case there's a random cell with a lot of decimal places

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two ways that you can do that.

-Select your range and change the number format:

```
Range("myrange").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
```

-Loop through all the cells in your range and apply the Round function to each of them.  In VBA you won't be able to use the Round function on a whole range at one time.

```
For Each currentcell In myRange
    currentcell.Value = Math.Round(currentcell.Value, 2)
Next
```

(pseudocode above; you'll need a better For..Next loop to loop through all the cells in your range.)

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried the first suggestion and it worked how I wanted.  I really wanted to do a whole range at once to try and save time