# Rounding to 2 decimal places using VBA

Tags: excel, rounding-error, vba

I am writing a program that sums information I enter by month (column) and by person (row), but I am having trouble with a rounding issue.  I have seen other places that it is possible to name a range, then format the cells in that range to round to 2 decimal places, but I am new to VBA and the pseudo code the answer was written in wasn't enough to help me.

Below is the link to the answer I found that fits my problem, but I am having trouble implementing the pseudo code.

[VBA Round Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358043/vba-round-function)

Answer (score -1):

Use the VBA round function, see here: http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/round_vba.php

But if you just want the columns to be shown as two decimal places, why not just set the format of the columns to be be 2 decimal places? There's no need to use VBA code. Here are the instructions on how to do that:

1. Highlight the entire column
2. Right click, choose "Format Cells...",
3. Click the Number tab, and then choose "Custom" for the Category.
4. Choose 0.00 for the Type.
5. Now try typing 1.2345 in one of the cells in this column, and when you leave the cell it will be 1.23.

Comment: This is what i am looking for, but how do i apply it to just columns G-S, I have an unknown number of rows and need all of the values to be rounded.

Comment: @Mike - I think maybe you are over complicating things, see my latest edit for an easier solution. Or maybe I misunderstood what you are trying to do.

Comment: I tried what your edit is previously, this however, doesn't work for the cells that the program is auto summing.

Comment: I found my solution, I had the variable declared as "long", when i needed it to be "currency" to get the numbers in the proper format.